# How to properly depict external object on UML diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Suppose you have a `Parser` class that reads the file and does something with the data it contains. On a diagram how to you show that it gets data from some entity that is not represented by a class, but rather exists separately as, in this example - file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to show the structure.  Use a class or interface, as UML does not have to mean a Java class, you can also use an artifact which is more part of the deployment notation, but is fine to use elsewhere.  If you think about it a file is a fairly concrete concept, especially if it has a name.

From the OMG UML spec:

> ### 10.3.1 Artifact (from Artifacts, Nodes)
>
> An artifact is the specification of a physical piece of information
>   that is used or produced by a software development process, or by
>   deployment and operation of a system. Examples of artifacts include
>   model files, source files, scripts, and binary executable files, a
>   table in a database system, a development deliverable, or a
>   word-processing document, a mail message.